# How to get variable with value of HTML5 video duration

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have this structure, and I'm always getting the right duration number when asking console to log var inside the 'loadedmetadata', but outside those listeners, it's always 0 for both dur1 and dur2.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dur1 = dur2 = dur3 = 0,
        video1 = $('.video1'),
        video2 = $('.video2');

    (function(){
        video1.on('loadedmetadata', function() {
            var dur1 = video1[0].duration;
            console.log(dur1); // getting the right value
        });
        video2.on('loadedmetadata', function() {
            var dur2 = video2[0].duration;
            console.log(dur2); // geting the right value
        });

        console.log(dur1, dur2); // always getting 0  

    }());
});
```

Code example: http://cdpn.io/e/dXomLX

And obviously, I usually want to use variables outside those event listeners.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

you need to make three changes...

1. Move the var declaration for dur1 and dur2 outside the document ready function so they're available everywhere:

   ```
   var dur1 = dur2 = dur3 = 0;
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var video1 = $('.video1'),
       video2 = $('.video2');
   ```
2. don't declare them as a var inside the `loadedmetadata` function:

   ```
   dur1 = video1[0].duration;
   ```
3. don't try to display them immediately (as your current "outside" does) because it gets to that code and displays the initial values before the metadata loaded function has a chance to run. You may want to set a flag to indicate that the metadata has been loaded, or simply rely on a timer

   ```
   setTimeout('console.log(\'outside: \' + dur1, dur2)', 1000);
   ```